# a tall, slim woman vs a short fat man - problems with a comma

Tags: adjectives, commas

> At the 2012 US Track and Field Championships, **a tall, slim woman**
>   in a tracksuit watched the long jump final.

Source: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/othersports/article-2574382/Hall-Fame-Jack-Joyner-Kersee-Heptathlons-original-Golden-Girl-First-Lady-track-field.html

[image]
Why is there a commma after the word "tall"? I'd guess that it shouldn't be a comma because "tall" belongs to SIZE and "slim" belongs to SHAPE.

> A young woman was assaulted by **a short fat man** with dirty trainers
>   in a busy Plymouth street.

Source: http://www.plymouthherald.co.uk/woman-attacked-in-busy-plymouth-street-by-short-fat-man-wearing-dirty-trainers/story-29536571-detail/story.html
"short" belongs to SIZE and "fat" belongs to SHAPE and there is no comma?
Why is it so confusing? The categories are the same.

Comment: There is a difference between _style_ and _rule_. The Royal Order of Adjectives is not a _rule_, and the inclusion of commas in a series of adjectives is not governed by a _rule_, either. In the newspaper quotes, the writers are using "journalese." It's a _style_, and you'll see many such usages. Don't worry about them!

Answer (score 1):

The main reason there is a difference between comma usage for

> a tall, slim woman
>   a short fat man

is stylistic.

Please note your examples are drawn from two different newspapers which may have their own, different style guides.  One is a national publication and the other is regional.

The comma may or may not be included without any loss of understanding for either.  I have always been taught to include commas in this situation.

Answer (score -2):

A comma is used because "tall" and "slim" are **coordinate adjectives** which modify "woman". [Here is an article](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives) which explains how they are used in more detail.

Your second quote about the "short fat man" is grammatically incorrect. It should read:

> "A young woman was assaulted by a short, fat man with dirty trainers..."

Comment: But I've seen a lot of examples without a comma: http://www.bbc.co.uk/berkshire/content/articles/2005/08/03/3bs_review_feature.shtml
Here's the BBC article. I think it's a recognized website.

Comment: @masterkomp - Yes: that's because there is no _rule_ governing this usage. It's a matter of _preference_ and _style,_ especially when the writer is a journalist. It's common for learners of English to worry about this, but you shouldn't. Follow the recommendations in whatever chart you like in your _own_ writing, but don't worry when writers omit or add a comma. And don't forget: **all** websites are "recognized!" Anyone can create a website.

Comment: But what if I want to correct my students' mistakes? What style/rule should I follow?

Comment: @masterkomp, You teach English, yet you are perhaps not fluent yourself? This is disturbing. Be that as it may, here is a useful [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/413) about the "Oxford comma" which contains useful information about commas generally. A good, short summary on commas is [here](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000070.htm).

Comment: Firstly, I'm not a native speaker of English. Secondly, I know the rules from grammar books. I want to clarify some rules, make sure that some pattern is correct. So if there aren't any rules, what are grammar books for?

Comment: PS I know the rules you gave me in these links. I want other opinions relating to my main post.

Comment: You seem to be saying ***a short fat man*** without a comma is "grammatically incorrect". That's complete nonsense.

Comment: RE: _What style/rule should I follow?_ You should tell your students to be **consistent**. We can find instances of both styles from reputable sources, so both styles are acceptable. Generally speaking, though, writers should avoid following one set of guidelines in one paragraph, and then using another in the next.